# form not submitting after js and ajax validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am using ajax to validate user credentials after i have validated the user has input data into the required fields but afterwords the form is not being submitted. I have created a variable `submit_form` which is supposed to determine if the default form action is performed or not but when set it to `true` and console log it, it still seems to continue it's default value of `false`, why is it like that and how can change it so my form can submit after the username and password are correct.
Here is my screenshot of the console in the browser
[image]

Here is a my code:

```
/*global $*/
/*global _*/

$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
    $('#login-form').on('submit', function(event) {
        var form_items = {
            username: { required: true, name: 'Username' },
            password: { required: true, name: 'Password' },
            token: {}
        };   

        var $login_form = $(this);
        var submit_form = false;
        var errors;
        var display = '';
        var data;

        var validation = new Validation( form_items );
        validation = validation.check( $login_form['context'] );

        // If any element has the class for errors, remove the class
        $('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');

        if ( validation.passed() ) {
            data = JSON.stringify( validation.getData() );
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "ajax/login.ajax.php",
                data: { info: data }
            }).done(function( response ) {
                response = JSON.parse(response);

                // if the error list display is there, remove it
                $('.bg-danger').parent().remove();
                if ( _.has(response, 'errors') ) {
                    errors = response['errors'];
                    display = '<div class="form-group"><ul class="bg-danger">';
                    if ( _.isArray(errors) || _.isObject(errors) ) {
                        _.each( errors, function(elem, index, list) {
                            display += '<li>' + elem + '</li>';
                        });
                    } else {
                        display += '<li>' + errors + '</li>';
                    }
                    display += '</ul></div>';
                    $login_form.prepend( display );
                } else {
                    submit_form = true;
                }
            });
            console.log( submit_form );
        } else {
            // if the error list display is there, remove it
            $('.bg-danger').parent().remove();

            errors = validation.getErrors();
            display = '<div class="form-group"><ul class="bg-danger">';
            _.each( errors, function(elem, index, list) {
                var $form_element = $('#'+index); // get form element
                $form_element.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
                display += '<li>' + elem + '</li>';
            });
            display += '</ul></div>';
            $login_form.prepend( display );
        }

        if ( !submit_form ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: because you can not return from an Ajax request.

Comment: @epascarello any suggestions on how go about the issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: You will need to submit the form via code